# Generic type in generic constraint

Tags: c#, generics

I want to be able to specify something like this:

```
public abstract class ColumnFilter<TCell, TFilterControl> : ColumnFilter
    where TFilterControl : FilterControl<>, new()
    where TCell : IView, new()
{
}
```

Class FilterControl<> is a base class. I can not know what will be the generic argument for FilterControl<>.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use unbound generic types in type constraints. You'd have to add a third type parameter, like this:

```
public abstract class ColumnFilter<TCell, TFilterControl, TFilterControlType> : ColumnFilter
    where TFilterControl : FilterControl<TFilterControlType>, new()
    where TCell : IView, new()
{
}
```

Or create a non-generic base type of `FilterControl`:

```
public FilterControl { }
public FilterControl<T> : FilterControl { }

public abstract class ColumnFilter<TCell, TFilterControl> : ColumnFilter
    where TFilterControl : FilterControl, new()
    where TCell : IView, new()
{
}
```

You can also make the base type `abstract` with `internal` constructors if you want to force consumers to use your generic derived type.

Comment: I thought to do so, but it is not convenient. It seems that no other way.

Answer (score 2):

`ColumnFilter` will have to be told what that type will be.

Add a third generic type parameter, like so:

```
public abstract class ColumnFilter<TCell, TFilterControl, TFilter> : ColumnFilter
    where TFilterControl : FilterControl<TFilter>, new()
    where TCell : IView, new()
{
}
```

Comment: I thought to do so, but it is not convenient. It seems that no other way.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you think FilterControl<> is a base class. It is not, think of it as a template. It has no substance until it is given the context of what is inside the <>.